# What does "1 x Tacet" mean?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, terminology, repeats

What does `1x Tacet` mean?

[image: excerpt with "1x Tacet" marking]

Does it mean "play the following in 1st round only"?

Comment: A more conventional way to write this would be ( 2nd X only ) instead, unless there are 3rd, 4th, 5th endings or something along those lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[Tacet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacet)" is a Latin musical term meaning (literally) "it is silent". in this case, the number preceding it identifies which repetitions it is to be silent for. Here, the first time through is to be silent. The second time through, do play that segment.

In jazz and other more 'modern' genres, tacet is often used for very short breaks (such as one or two bars). In classical and orchestral music, it is usually reserved for longer breaks (such as entire movements).

Comment: In jazz etc. Tacet is often used to indicate a few beats where everyone (or maybe just all of the rhythm section) stops playing.  But it's equally commonly  used as in the example above (which would have been clearer had there been some notes - it's hard to tell if you're taceting or not during a rest!)  As stated, "1x Tacet" over a repeated section is equivalent to "Play 2nd X only".